# Why is registering a sidebar for each page causing my sidebars to reset?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have the following code in my functions.php

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') ){

    $pages=get_pages();

    foreach($pages as $page){

        register_sidebar(array('name'=>$page->post_title, 'sort_column'=>'ID','sort_order'=>'ASC', 'id'=>$page->ID));

    }
}
```

It works beautifully to give me a sidebar for each page. The problem is that the sidebar contest are constantly being reset. Every time I go back to my widgets page, the sidebars are all blank. I can usually still see the contents on the actual site, unless I update something in a different sidebar. If I take out the loop and just use register_sidebar to register a single sidebar, everything seems to work fine. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap this in a function then add it to the widgets_init action.  Also the register sidebar function does not have $arguments for sort_column or sort_order.  I would also change the id to `'sidebar-'.$page->ID`

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'prefix_register_sidebars' );
function prefix_register_sidebars() {
    foreach($pages as $page){
        register_sidebar( array(
        'name'=>$page->post_title, 
        'id'=> 'sidebar-'.$page->ID,
        'before_widget'   => '<div id="%1$s" class="'.$page->slug.' widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'    => '</div>',
        'before_title'    => '<h3>',
        'after_title'     => '</h3>'
        )
        ); 
}
```

Comment: I had tried using widgets_init, but got the same results. Unfortunately, widgets_init is pretty poorly documented (IMO). I think I fixed it by using `'sidebar-'.$page->ID`. I found another blog where someone had trouble using uppercase letters, and I noticed the codex says that ids "Must be all in lowercase" so that probably was the issue. Things seem to be working properly now, but sometimes there has been a delay before things get reset so I will wait 24 hours and then mark your answer as correct if everything is still good.